# angularjs getting data from a url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get json data from the url and assign it to a variable. I use a service that looks like this

```
app.service('dataService', function($http) {
  this.getdata = function(callbackFunc) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/records/json/',
     }).success(function(data){
        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
        callbackFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
 }
});
```

and my controller looks like this

```
app.controller('ReCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, dataService){ 
   dataService.getdata(function(dataResponse) {
      $scope.fields = dataResponse; 
   });
   ....
```

But I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getdata' of undefined`. I dont know what i am doing wrong. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not injecting your service (`dataService`) into your controller:

```
app.controller('ReCtrl', 
   ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService){ 
   dataService.getdata(function(dataResponse) {
      $scope.fields = dataResponse; 
   });
   ....
```

Note the extra string `'dataService'` after `'$scope'` while defining the controller `ReCtrl`.

Comment: Thanks, noob mistake. I appreciate your help.